# How to look up a field value using foreignkey in Django

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class Camera(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    camera_number = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False,
                                        validators=[
                                          MaxValueValidator(1000),
                                          MinValueValidator(1)])
    camera_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False, unique=True)


class BaseImage(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    base_image_filename = "base_images/" + str(Camera.slug) + "/%H"
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=300, upload_to=base_image_filename)
```

What I am trying to do is to create the filename in BaseImage that contains the data in the slug variable of the corresponding Camera record.  A camera can have many BaseImages but each BaseImage can only match to one Camera.

What I get in the name is something like "base_images/<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f6006bd9b70>/20/camera_1.jpg".

What do I need to change to get the slug field value as part of the filename ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a method and pass a reference to that method:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class BaseImage(models.Model):
    def get_image_filename(self, filename):
        h = now().strftime('%H')
        return f'base_images/{self.url.slug}/{h}/{filename}'
    
    url = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=300, upload_to=get_image_filename)
```

Comment: Cool - thank you so much ... its almost there. The %H part in the original format I had was there to add the current hour as part of the name.  It now just as "%H" as a string and not the hour.  

Figured it out:

    def get_image_filename(self, filename):
        return f'base_images/{self.url.slug}/' + str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + f'/{filename}'

unless there is a more elegant method